# Receiving the following error

Tags: errors, equations

[image]

```
\noindent P_{(i,D_n)}=\frac{{\tau }^{\alpha }_{(i,D_n\ )}\ \ {\eta }^{\beta }_{(i,D_n\ )}}{\sum^k_{j=0}{{\tau }^{\alpha }_{\ (j,D_n\ \ )}\ \ {\eta }^{\beta }_{(\ j,D_n\ )}}}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \eqref{GrindEQ__1_}          

\noindent where  $P_{(i,D_n)}$ is the probability of choosing data object $D_n$  in cluster i , $\tau (i,D_n)$ and $\eta (i,D_n)$ are the pheromone and heuristic information assigned to data object $D_n$  in cluster i respectively, $\alphaup$ and $\betaup$ are constant parameters that determines the relative influence of the pheromone and heuristic information and k  is the number of clusters.
```

Comment: Please provide a proper MWE.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide the code for a small document which produces the error and tell us which error you receive. Copy and past code and errors as text - don't use screenshots as these cannot be used to recreate the problem.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use maths stuff in text mode.

Comment: Also, do note that LaTeX is perfectly capable of numbering your equations automatically. Instead of `\[ <math> <lots of spaces> (<number>)\]`, write `\begin{equation} <math> \end{equation}`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

Observe that I've radically simplified and streamlined your math-related code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{GrindEQ_1}
P_{i,D_n} = \frac{\tau^\alpha_{i,D_n} \, \eta^\beta_{i,D_n}}{
     \sum^k_{j=1} \tau^\alpha_{j,D_n} \, \eta^\beta_{j,D_n}}\,, 
     \quad i=1,\dots,k          
\end{equation} % no blank line after "\end{equation}"
where $P_{i,D_n}$ is the probability of choosing data object~$D_n$ in 
cluster~$i$; $\tau_{i,D_n}$ and $\eta_{i,D_n}$ are the pheromone and 
heuristic information assigned to data object~$D_n$ in cluster~$i$, 
respectively; $\alpha$ and~$\beta$ are constant parameters that determine 
the relative influence of the pheromone and heuristic information; and~$k$  
is the number of clusters.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote once more just for the patience `;-)`